# Alternative to selectionchanged event of listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there an alternative ItemsControl (something very similar to ListBox), or alternatively an event in ListBox that is raised when the last selected object is selected "again"?  I can't use code-behind because of some requirement, so the solution has to be in XAML ONLY.  :(

Comment: Have you considered listening to a mouse click event? That seems to be the only way to "reselect" an already selected listBox item.

Comment: @user845279 : I have tried mouse click event problem with it is, if mouse click happens on listbox but not any listboxitem, its gets fired. Since I have to xaml only I can't check if click was on listbox or listbox.

Comment: You could embed the code for your event handler in XAML or is that a problem with your requirement. Because technically it is not code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not achieve the entire thing using just XAML :(. But I used mouse click events to achieve it. (thanks to suggestions of [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845279/user845279) ). The answer may not be perfect, but thought of sharing it since it may help others.

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    private SelectionChangedEventArgs cachedArgs;
    private int state;

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        this.AddHandler(Mouse.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(CustomListBox_MouseDown), true);
        state = 0;
    }

    void CustomListBox_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (state == 1) // I don't want to re-raise event if ListBox had raised it already. 
        {
            this.OnSelectionChanged(cachedArgs);
        }
        state = 3;
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        state = 1;
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Responds to a list box selection change by raising a <see cref="E:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanged"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Provides data for <see cref="T:System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs"/>.</param>
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        cachedArgs = e;
        state = 2;
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used three different states. PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event is raised always before other two events, so state 1. If there is a SelectionChanged event raised, it will be before Mouse.MouseDownEvent so state 2 and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use a Blend SDK behavior InvokeMethod to execute a method on the ViewModel when the mouseclick event is fired.

[This article is about Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160892/Binding-Events-to-Methods-in-the-Silverlight-MVVM) but discusses the same behavior that can be used in WPF